# MySQL service stuck in starting state after restoring database failed

Tags: mysql, mysql5.7

I was restoring a MySQL database using the import wizard, importing from dump files. This took a while but in doing so the disk ran out of space so never finished importing.

Now, the `MySQL57` service is stuck in a "Starting" state even after a restart.

There are error log files but I cannot open them in a text editor due to it being binary encoding.

Is there a way for me to remove the failed schema from MySQL to allow the service to start up again, without me having to reinstall everything and start again?

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` show?  (Or can you not even get to that point?)

Comment: Can you, instead, have the dump files on another machine, and import across the network?  Or have you increased the disk size?

Comment: (This would be better handled in dba.stackexchange.com )

Comment: It did eventually start back up again after a few hours. I was then able to get rid of the database.